# Updating a nested JsObject in Play Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have an input json that looks like this:

```
{
    "dashboard": {
            "id": 0,
            "originalTitle": "Test dashboard",
            "rows": [
                    {
                            "collapse": false,
                            "editable": true,
                            "height": "250px",
                            "panels": [],
                            "title": "Row"
                    }
            ],
            "schemaVersion": 0,
            "tags": [
                    "T35T-DA5H-80ARD"
            ],
            "timezone": "browser",
            "title": "Test dashboard",
            "version": 0
    },
    "overwrite": true
}
```

I want to update the "panels" field by adding an element to the list. What I can do at the moment is pick the value of "panels":

```
val json = Json.parse(dashboardJson).validate[JsObject].get
json.transform(
  (__ \ 'dashboard).json.pickBranch
  (
    (__ \ 'rows).json.pickBranch
    (
      (__ \\ 'panels).json.pick
    )
  )
)
```

This results in:

```
JsSuccess({"dashboard":{"rows":[]}},/dashboard/rows//panels)
```

But when I try to update it like this, it doesn't work:

```
json.transform(
  (__ \ 'dashboard).json.pickBranch
  (
    (__ \ 'rows).json.pickBranch
    (
      (__ \\ 'panels).json.update
      (
        __.read[JsObject].map { o => o ++ Json.obj( "bla" -> "blabla" ) }
      )
    )
  )
)
```

This results in:

```
JsError(List((/dashboard/rows,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject),WrappedArray())))))
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: panels is `JsArray` not `JsObject`

Comment: @andrey.ladniy I tried to do it like this ` __.read[JsArray].map { o => o ++ JsArray(Seq(JsString("bla"))) }` and got `JsError(List((/dashboard/rows,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject),WrappedArray()))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must traverse every `JsArray` (rows and panels):

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json._

val t = (
  (__ \ "dashboard" \ "rows").json.update(
    of[JsArray](
      list(
        (__ \ "panels").json.update(
          of[JsArray].map{ case JsArray(arr) => JsArray(arr :+ JsString("sss"))}
        )
      ).map(JsArray)
    )
  )
)

json.transform(t)

scala> JsSuccess({
  "dashboard": {
    "id": 0,
    "originalTitle": "Test dashboard",
    "rows": [
      {
        "collapse": false,
        "editable": true,
        "height": "250px",
        "panels": [
          "sss"
        ],
        "title": "Row"
      }
    ],
    "schemaVersion": 0,
    "tags": [
      "T35T-DA5H-80ARD"
    ],
    "timezone": "browser",
    "title": "Test dashboard",
    "version": 0
  },
  "overwrite": true
},/dashboard/rows)
```

Comment: is there a `json.transform` in front of this call? I cannot resolve `of` and `list`...

Comment: `of` and `list` equals `Reads.of` and `Reads.list`